# Microsoft Excel 2016 - how to match records of one spreadsheet to another based on a common 'name' attribute

Tags: excel, match, spreadsheet, excel-2016

I have two tables on an Excel spreadsheet. The first table contains around 20,000 records, whilst the second contains a few hundred. Both tables contain a 'name' column containing names in text format. Some of the records in this second table have matching names to some of the records in the first table. Is there a way to rearrange the rows in the second table to match up with the relevant rows in the first table (i.e. to move those rows to the same rows as in the first table)?The remaining entries that do not match can be deleted.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjzsX.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by rearrange? Place in same row as first table? Place in same order as first table? What about the rows in the second table that don't have a match? Do they remain untouched? Do they move to the bottom? Do you want the actual original cells themselves to change or are you OK with a "helper" column? Please clarify all of these details, and show en example of your data. Your question is ambiguous right now.

Comment: mmmmm. not sure if this will work, but try dividing your data in 2 different workbooks (1 table in each workbook) and then join them using Microsoft Query. That way, you can relate both tables using that column containing matching names as index. But this is a shot in the dark without data example.

Comment: Couldn't you just use **`VLookUp`** or **`Index+Match`** in your second table?